# Why is my overridden ClaimsIdentityFactory.CreateAsync() method not called?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have created a `MyClaimsIdentity` class that inherits from `ClaimsIdentity`. When I run my app the `CreateAsync` method is never called and I never see the custom claims that I added.

There are no compile errors and if I add the default constructor I can see that this class is constructed however no breakpoints are hit within the `CreateAsync` method.

```
public class MyClaimsFactory : ClaimsIdentityFactory<User, string>
{
    public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(UserManager<User, string> manager, User user, string authenticationType)
    {
        var identity = await base.CreateAsync(manager, user, authenticationType);
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName))
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("given_name", user.FirstName));
        }

        return identity;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using IdentityServer by chance?  If so this may help you... https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1204

Comment: Yes, I am using IdentityServer V3.  The link you provide is exactly the issue I was having.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting this as the answer,  thanks.

Are you using IdentityServer by chance? If so this may help you... [github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1204](http://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1204) –  Jeremy Aug 3 at 16:13

Comment: Typically if you put another user's work as an answer, you should make that answer Community Wiki.

Comment: Sorry,  I wasn't sure what to do when the answer was a comment.  I will do that next time.